# shell script variable use

Tags: bash, shell, variables, ksh

I'll get to the meat and bones:

```
MY_VAR=6
until [$MY_VAR = 0]
do
dir/dir_$MY_VAR.log
ps | grep "NAME_$MY_VAR.ksh"
check some things
if [results = ok]
echo "program $MY_VAR sucessful"
else
echo "program $MY_VAR failure"
MY_VAR = `expr $MY_VAR - 1`
done
```

Now I am getting the following errors MY_VAR not found and [6: not found, so I'm assuming a rather noobish mistake. I feel the logic is sound enough just a simple syntax error I am making somewhere by the looks of the two errors I think it could be in the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a space after `[` and before `]` since `[` is actually a command and not a delimiter.

Here is your script re-written in Bash (or ksh):

```
my_var=6
until ((my_var == 0))
do
    dir/dir_$my_var.log    # I have no idea what this is supposed to be
    ps | grep "NAME_$my_var.ksh"
    # check some things
    if [[ $results = ok ]]
    then
        echo "program $my_var successful"
    else
        echo "program $my_var failure"
        ((my_var--))
    fi
done
```

However:

```
for my_var in {6..1}
do
    dir/dir_$my_var.log    # I have no idea what this is supposed to be
    ps | grep "NAME_$my_var.ksh"
    # check some things
    if [[ $results = ok ]]
    then
        echo "program $my_var successful"
    else
        echo "program $my_var failure"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I get the error MY_VAR--: more tokens expected, could you elaborate on your solution such as the use of (()) and [[]]

Comment: @Jewsef: Using which shell and on which line of which version of the scripts from my answer? One thing to note, I had changed the case of the variable name, but I did so inconsistently. That may have caused some trouble. Sorry about that - I've fixed it. In Bash and ksh double square brackets [enable some additional capabilities](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031). Using double parentheses for numeric comparisons allows you to use `==` and `>`, for example, instead of the ugly `-eq` and `-gt`. It also allows you to do arithmetic operations such as the decrement `((my_var--))` shown.

Comment: @Jewsef: I just noticed that the script in your question is missing the `fi` to close the `if`. I copied your script into my answer and missed fixing that (now fixed). That could be the source of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Your two errors are caused by:

- `until [$MY_VAR = 0]`
- `MY_VAR = $(expr $MY_VAR - 1)`

[I've used $() instead of backticks because I couldn't get backticks into the code section]

The first problem is the lack of spaces around the square brackets - on both ends. The shell is looking for the command `[6` (after expanding `$MY_VAR`), instead of `[` (have a look at `/usr/bin/[` - it's actually a program). You should also use `-eq` to do numeric comparisons. `=` should work ok here, but leading zeros can break a string comparison where a numeric comparison would work:

```
until [ "$MY_VAR" -eq 0 ]
```

The second problem is you have spaces in your variable assignment. When you write `MY_VAR = ...` the shell is looking for the command `MY_VAR`. Instead write it as:

```
MY_VAR=`expr $MY_VAR - 1`
```

These answers directly answer your questions, but you should study Dennis Williamson's answer for better ways to do these things.

Comment: It's true that `[` exists as `/usr/bin/[`, but it's a shell builtin, too, and as such has precedence. Be careful of relying on the leading zero behavior, `[ 008 -eq 8 ]` works, but `[[ 008 -eq 8 ]]` gives a `value too great for base` error. Backticks should be avoided anyway, use of `$()` is preferred.